# batch tiff image processing

Tags: image-processing, tiff

I have about 100 tiff images an I need to draw into each of them one transparent image on specific coordinates and save.
It would be very time consuming to do it manualy using editor. 
Is there any commandline software for windows, which can combine two images using XOR or AND operation.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Fiji/ImageJ](http://fiji.sc/Fiji). It has an [Image Calculator](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-29.html#sub%3aImage-Calculator...) that supports AND and XOR operations.

Record a set of commands within the user interface first (*Plugins > Macros > Record...*), such as:

```bsh
open("/path/to/first-image.tif");
open("/path/to/second-image.tif");
imageCalculator("AND create", "first-image.tif","second-image.tif");
```

You can then perform the same action [on a whole set of images](http://fiji.sc/How_to_apply_a_common_operation_to_a_complete_directory) from within the GUI, or from the command line [in headless mode](http://fiji.sc/Headless).

Answer (score 0):

Look into ImageMagick, it's a powerful program that allows you to do command-line operations on files such as converting, scaling, and merging images.

It also easily takes multiple files, so I think it would be perfect for your situation.